# Revealed Close button in DIV not responsive on first click (or tap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a problem where a revealed DIV does not close on the first attempt. The user has to click at least once, anywhere on the page - doesn't have to be the close button, before they can click CLOSE to actually close the DIV. First off though, there is a short lead up before the DIV.

I use a jquery mobile popup in my page to contain a single text field and submit button. It looks something like this (minus the layout). The user submits their note through this popup.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic"  data-corners="false">
    <textarea rows="9" name="note" id="AttitionalNoteText"></textarea>
    <a href="#" data-mini="true" id="submitnote" data-role="button">Submit</a>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" id="cancelSubmitNote" data-mini="true" data-role="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

When the user hits submit, I perform an ajax response to send the text to the server and upon success follow it up by revealing a hidden DIV as confirmation to the user. I use a DIV instead of another popup since I realized that chaining popups is not possible within my ajax call.

```
// this is called when the user hits submit in the popup
$("#submitnote").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // do stuff here to pass textstring

    $("#popupBasic").hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: textstring,
        url: '/something/addnote',
        success: function (data) {
            showConfirm(data); // upon success call the function below to open the DIV
        }
    });
    $("#AttitionalNoteText").val("");
});

function showConfirm(data) {
    document.getElementById("confirmMsg").innerHTML = data;
    $("#confirmBox").show();
}

// this is to close that DIV
$("#closeConfirmBox").click(function (e) {
    $("#confirmBox").hide();
});
```

Here's that simple DIV along with a close button.

```
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div id="confirmMsg" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px;">
        this message gets replaced with whatever ajax call returned
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="closeConfirmBox" data-role="button">Close</a>
</div>
```

It seems that after the popup hides and my DIV comes up, the mouse does not show as a finger pointer until I've click somewhere on the page once. Only then can I use the Close button on the DIV properly. The same happens on mobile, I have to tab somewhere on the screen before I can tap again on Close. What can I do about this?

Comment: Only "close" button didnt work at first click, or anyone element on confirm box?

Comment: That's a good question. Other elements on the page cannot be manipulated until after that first click.

Comment: It means that have one transparent element in front the others, and this disapears when you click. If you find out what, you can remove this by Js after your ajax function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#popupBasic").hide(); 
$("#popupBasic-screen").hide();
```

Added the above just before the ajax call.

I think this wouldn't have been a problem if there was a proper solution to .popup("close") being undefined.

Comment: See my answer. $("#popupBasic").popup( "close" ); is the proper way to close a popup widget. API DOC: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-close

Comment: Unfortunately the function is undefined on my client's webpage, even with the latest jQuery. I think the issue has to do with initialization.

Comment: Where is the popup markup? It should be within the data-role="page" DIV at the same level as the header, content, footer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the popup widget's **[close method](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-close)**, you are just hiding the div and leaving the modal screen in place.

Change;

```
$("#popupBasic").hide();
```

To:

```
$("#popupBasic").popup( "close" );
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y1pot9mz/)**

BTW, if you do want to go with chained popups, have a look at this blog entry I wrote: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/